# Android Retrofit Setting Header Value Dynamically

Tags: android, header, retrofit

I have an android application in which an image is uploaded into the server. I am using retrofit library for uploading the image. For that there is a header part which is a access_token that is dynamically added when the call is made.

**ApiInterface**

```
    @Headers({"source: android"})
    @Multipart
    @POST("doImageUpload.php")
    Call<ResponseBody> imageUpload(@Header("access_token") String accesstoken,@Part("username") RequestBody  username, @Part("action") RequestBody  action,@Part("image_data") RequestBody  image_data  );
```

**ImageUpload Function**

```
public void imageupload(String imagepath)
{

    final ProgressDialog mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
    mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    mProgressDialog.show();
    String action = "imageUpload";

    String access = mPreferences.getString("accesstoken","");
    ApiInterface apiService =
            ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
    final String TAG = "Image Upload";

    MediaType type = MediaType.parse("text/plain; charset=utf-8");


    Call<ResponseBody> call = apiService.imageUpload(@Header(RequestBody.create(type,mPreferences.getString("accesstoken", "")))
            RequestBody.create(type,mPreferences.getString("UserName", "")),RequestBody.create(type,imagepath),RequestBody.create(type,action));

    call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody>call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
            ResponseBody ResponseBody = response.body();
            Log.d("requrl",response.raw().request().url().toString());
            Log.d(TAG, "signup" + ResponseBody.toString());


            if (mProgressDialog.isShowing())
                mProgressDialog.dismiss();

            try {

                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response.body().string());

                Log.d("chkva","--"+obj.getBoolean("status"));


                }


            } catch (Exception exception){

                Log.d("Error123","sad"+exception.getMessage());

            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody>call, Throwable t) {
            // Log error here since request failed
            Log.e(TAG, t.toString());
        }
    });

}
```

My access_token is stored in shared preference and I have to add this access_token to the image upload function.I don't know whether if I am using the correct method or not to add the header. Can anybody help me in this situation.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The header type of param in `imageUpload()` is STRING, you just need fill a String header.

```
Call<ResponseBody> call = apiService.imageUpload(mPreferences.getString("accesstoken", ""), 
            RequestBody.create(type,mPreferences.getString("UserName", "")),RequestBody.create(type,imagepath), RequestBody.create(type,action));
```

Comment: and you can ref this:https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-add-custom-request-header